# run on android studio adb device connect mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, localhost, adb

I'm a beginner and this is my first time to run my app that connect to my mysql localhost, but my laptop did not support the emulator. And I am using my device to run the app. Here I want to ask why did the app is not functioning? and my registration form did not connect to the localhost.

Comment: if your app on your device is attempting to connect to mysql host 'localhost' then it's looking for a mysql server on your device, not your laptop.

Comment: Hi, basically I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8-SnOF0wkI and there is no error but My app cant connect to mysql. I'm using my localhost and ip address to connect to the localhost, and I'm running the app on my own device. And I dont have any idea which part I missed or wrong